# Extracting rows from excel worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

A problem that I am trying to do is extract rows out of a spreadsheet. The spreadsheet has over 1200 entries. I have split them up into relevant worksheets so the information can be used. Each of the individual codes will be a worksheet

A sample of the data looks like

[image]

The formula that I have found is and trying to run from a separate work sheet is

```
INDEX(Master!$A$2:$D$13, SMALL(IF((INDEX(Master!$A$2:$D$13,,4,1)="wap"), 
  MATCH(ROW(Master!$A$2:$D$13),ROW(Master!$A$2:$D$13)), “”), ROWS(A2:$A$2)), ,1)
```

It fails on

```
MATCH(ROW(Master!$A$2:$D$13),ROW(Master!$A$2:$D$13))
```

*Getting the dreaded #N/A*

I need some help in solving the problem and a brief explanation of the solution would be helpful.

Unfortunately, it has to be done by formula, as I don't have access rights for a VBA query.

Comment: What I would like is to have all the same codes on individual worksheets as well having the master sheet

Comment: unfortunately it will be sent to a couple of members of the team and though that is whats being done at the moment, the issues start if  there is any work on the master. Trust me, on this

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
=IFERROR(
    INDEX(Master!$A$2:$D$13, 
        SMALL(
            IF(
                INDEX(Master!$A$2:$D$13,,4)="wap",
                INDEX(Master!$A$2:$D$13,,1), 
                COUNTA(Master!$A$2:$A$13)+1
                ), 
            ROWS(A2:$A$2)
            ),
        COLUMN()
        )
    ,"")
```

This must be entered as an array function. Instead of clicking out of the cell or pressing enter to exit the formula, press Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

The IF function iterates through every cell in column 4 of the Master array. If the Code is a match, the ID is passed. Otherwise, the number of master rows plus one is passed. This is important because it will produce an error in the final INDEX function, which will be escaped to "" (a blank string).

The SMALL function outputs the current row, or key in the generated array. The final INDEX function gets the intersect of the current column and the chosen row. Just copy this across however many columns you have on each sheet and down the number of rows that should be returned. Any additional rows (or columns) will pass the blank string. To be safe, I'd copy down the 1200 rows, but this could slow your processing (if it does, just set the calc mode to manual).